# Drawing transition diagram from transition table

Tags: finite-automata, transition-systems

I have a DFA transition table like
\begin{array}{cc|c|c}
                  &      & 0   & 1         \\ \hline
            \to   & p    & qs  & q    \\
            *     & q    & r   & qr    \\
            *     & qs   & r   & pqr      \\
                  & r    & s   & p    \\
            *     & s    & t   & p    \\
                  & t    & t   & t   \\
            *     & qr   &  rs & pqr    \\
            *     & pqr  & qrs & pqr      \\
            *     & rs   & s   & p\\
            *     & qrs  & rs  & pqr
\end{array}

I am not able to draw the transition diagram as it's getting too much complicated. Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT:** I drew the transition diagram but some of the lines were intersecting each other. Is there any way not to intersect those lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use an online graph editor, like [this one](https://csacademy.com/app/graph_editor/). In the settings set it to have directed edges and custom labels, and type a triplet $(s_1,s_2,v)$ for an edge from $s_1$ to $s_2$ with $v$ written on the edge.

---

However, this won't allow you to create "accepting" states, when you draw this yourself, add them by hand... If you prefer a slightly worse-looking editor, but one that can also have accepting states, consider [this automata drawer](http://madebyevan.com/fsm/)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try to do it with hand rather than switching to an online drawer that does the job for you. It is clear that you're struggling to keep track of the states and find it difficult to draw states and keep track of whether you've included a particular state or not.

- One good strategy will be to draw states on a big piece of paper with a decent amount of distance between them and mark the initial and final states.
- After that, start making transitions as per the transition table.
- As you finish making the transition on the diagram, mark or encircle it on the table as well. That way you'll know you've made that transition and will be able to keep track of each and every transaction.

Good luck :)

Comment: There is nothing new in your answer. I made a diagram but some of the transition lines intersect each other in that diagram and that is what I am not wanting.

Comment: You're still in your initial phases, so how does that matter at all even if it intersects. As per your question, you said its getting complicated. You should've mentioned that the lines are intersecting and you don't want that. Your question implied that you're not able to understand the transition diagram due to its complexities.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I am editing my question